# netbeans sql's statment using Like operator

Tags: netbeans-7

I am trying to pass value from Jcombobox and I used Like Operator in order to retrieve data from Database ..
I need to retrieve all data related to a chosen month from combobox

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Treatment WHERE Treatment_Date LIKE '?%'";
try {
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, cmb.getSelectedItem().toString());
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    table_PatuentReg.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Treatment WHERE Treatment_Date LIKE '"+cmb.getText().toString()+"%'";
```

Use this format.
this will help more...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query and add the % in the prepared statement value where we are setting the value for string.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Treatment WHERE Treatment_Date LIKE ?";
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, cmb.getSelectedItem().toString()+"?");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        table_PatuentReg.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting it directly in the `?` mark sign, like so

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Treatment WHERE Treatment_Date LIKE '"+cmb.getSelectedItem().toString()+"%'";

try {
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    table_PatuentReg.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```